# how json schema validate mixed property?

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

```
{ 'a': 343, 'b': 434 }
```

If I have a json data like above and the property 'a' and 'b' actually is a name give by user, so that can be any string. How can I create a json-schema to validate this?

Comment: I'm not sure you could, but you could translate it something that could, like `[{"key": "a", "value" 343}, {"key": "b", "value": 434}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the validation library you're using is based on a [relatively recent version of the JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html), you should be able to use [patternProperties](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor64) to validate properties with user-defined keys.

Here is a quick example that uses the javascript library [tv4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4) to perform the validation:

```
var schema = {
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$": {
            "title": "someUserDefinedPropertyName",
            "type": "number"
        }
    }
};

var valid = { "a": 1234, "b": 5678 };
var invalid = { "a": "1234", "b": 5678 };

alert("Validates? [should be true]: " + tv4.validate(valid, schema));
alert("Validates? [should be false]: " + tv4.validate(invalid, schema));
alert('Variable invalid, error at data path: ' + tv4.error.dataPath + '\n\nError Description:\n' + tv4.error.message);
```

For more information, I suggest reading the section of the Schema linked above, as well as checking out the [advanced examples on json-schema.org](http://json-schema.org/example2.html).

Comment: If it really can be *any* property name, then "additionalProperties" is more applicable.  You should probably mention that in your answer. :)